# How can I write YAML from dictionary containing munch without "!munch.Munch"?

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml

When writing a yaml file from a dictionary containing `munch.Munch` one gets "!munch.Munch" as part of the output. How can I avoid this behavior?

**Minimal example to show the problem**

```
data = {"A":"a", "B":munch.Munch({"C":"c"})}
with open("test.yaml", "w") as file:
    yaml.dump(data, file)
```

Produces:

```
A: a
B: !munch.Munch
  C: c
```

But wanted output is:

```
A: a
B:
  C: c
```

**Unfeasible solutions**

Of course one could simply walk through the dictionary recursively and convert every `munch.Munch` into a dictionary, but I believe that there is a better solution than that. Writing `munch.Munch` directly to a yaml file works as intended and the difference between `munch.Munch` and dict is so tiny - there must be a better way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `munch.Munch` is coming from [this munch repository](https://github.com/Infinidat/munch), you can use `safe_dump` instead of `dump` ([from the readme](https://github.com/Infinidat/munch/tree/2.5.0#serialization)).

```py
data = {"A":"a", "B":munch.Munch({"C":"c"})}
with open("test.yaml", "w") as file:
    yaml.safe_dump(data, file)
```

It produces what you want:

```yaml
A: a
B:
  C: c
```

Comment: Is it similarly possible to convert a dict containing munches to a dict containing only dicts?

Comment: Still in the readme:
> Finally, Munch converts easily and recursively to (unmunchify(), Munch.toDict()) and from (munchify(), Munch.fromDict()) a normal dict, making it easy to cleanly serialize them in other formats.

Comment: alright, so if it is unsure whether you are handling a dictionary or a munch (generic programming) one can munch.Munch(dict_or_munch).toDict(). Thank you very much!